# Solving N queens puzzle using pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads

I know how to solve n queens puzzle, using backtracking and recursion.

I was thinking how can I optimise this using multi-threading.

I am trying with p - threads.

Basically I am not able to understand where top apply threading, and where to join the threads.

As this is recursion, I am also,not able to understand how threading will work here.

--

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Comment: I am reading the books as well, but was in a hurry to find the way. Also I am not able to get how multi-threading will work with backtracking and recursion, and will it really optimise?

Comment: It may. Or may slow down things a big time. It depends on many things including how you actually write it. Anyhow, take a look at this paper from Intel that solves your problem in parallel - http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-code-ready-for-parallel-execution-with-intel-parallel-composer/

Comment: Actually the definitive answer is no it won't optimise, since it's an irregular problem, doing it recursively and synchronizing on the backtrack will cause a load imbalance. Hence it's a good example for the Cilk solution shown in the reference above which will balance the load through workstealing. (This is precisely why Cilk benchmarks have always included this problem)

Answer (score 3):

One way is using a queue to put each expansion into a queue instead of doing recursion. Have a pool of threads that pop an expansion and work on it:

```
create a state with an empty board and put it into the queue
create N threads with the following function
```

thread function:

```
while not done:
  1) pop a state S from the queue (use locks), if queue is empty,
     wait on a semaphore until there is an S
  2) expand state S
  2a) if S has feasible children then put them into the queue 
      except for one state SS, call it S and goto 2 
     (also signal the semaphore)
  2b) if S has no feasible children goto 1
end while
```

You can modify this for different algorithms

Comment: With pthreads you would probably use a condition variable rather than a semaphore to wait in step 1.